# Simulate / Trigger click on google.maps.places.Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, maps

I'm trying to simulate user click on first result of google maps places autocomplete.

This is the code I made to create the input which works great

```
var input = document.getElementById('search_addresses');
var options = {
   types: ['geocode'],
           };
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

after that what I want to simulate is focus on that input and click on first result it shows from google locations suggestions. I can easily get focus using

`input.focus();`

which opens suggestions windows from google

```
<div class="pac-container">
 <div class="pac-item"></div>
 <div class="pac-item"></div>
 <div class="pac-item"></div>
 <div class="pac-item"></div>
</div>
```

after that i'm stuck.

I first tried using click() event but it doesn't work. After, I tried to trigger enter key pressed event but I can't find a way to fire the event without actually click on something else.

Any idea?

Comment: You could try $('.pac-item', $('.pac-container'))[0].trigger('click'). When do you want to trigger the click? You might need a timeout.

Comment: Hi @Shrimp, thanks for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't work. But I found  way to get first element of the list:
`const nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName("pac-container");
var node = nodeList[1];` // somehow I got two .pac-container
`const innerList = node.getElementsByClassName("pac-item");
var list = innerList[0];
list.style.backgroundColor = "red";` // test to see if first element
`list.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicked'));
list.click();list.trigger('click');` //nothing happen
I really need just last click and its done. (yes timeout is needed)